# Software updater doesn't let me check some boxes

Tags: apt, updates, update-manager, gcc

Software updater on Ubuntu 22.04 shows two equal updates available for
`GCC: GNU Compiler collection (22 kb)` each, but their box cannot be checked.

If I run `sudo apt-get upgrade` on a terminal it finds 8 not updated packages:

```
gcc-10-base gcc-10-base:i386 python3-software-properties 
python3-update-manager software-properties-common software-properties-gtk 
update-manager update-manager-core
```

EDIT:

```
$ apt policy gcc-10-base
gcc-10-base:
  Installed: 10.5.0-1ubuntu1~20.04
  Candidate: 10.5.0-1ubuntu1~22.04
  Version table:
     10.5.0-1ubuntu1~22.04 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe amd64 Packages
 *** 10.5.0-1ubuntu1~20.04 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     10.3.0-15ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages
user@ubuntu:~$ apt policy gcc-10-base:i386
gcc-10-base:i386:
  Installed: 10.5.0-1ubuntu1~20.04
  Candidate: 10.5.0-1ubuntu1~22.04
  Version table:
     10.5.0-1ubuntu1~22.04 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe i386 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe i386 Packages
 *** 10.5.0-1ubuntu1~20.04 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     10.3.0-15ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe i386 Packages
```

What am I missing?

Comment: @user535733 thanks for the suggestion. Question edited

Comment: @user535733 is it bad? Why you say possible and what should I do? The system behaves rather stable to me.

Comment: Thanks. If you write an answer I'll accept it. when you say "reinstall" you mean which version exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked "what am I missing?"

Your `apt policy` output answers that question: You have 20.04 packages installed on a 22.04 system. That's why they won't upgrade.

```
 *** 10.5.0-1ubuntu1~20.04 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

It probably won't cause your system to crash or fail unexpectedly.

It does mean that you likely won't be able to release-upgrade to a future release of Ubuntu. You will need to back up your data and clean-install that new release of Ubuntu instead.

You cannot disable the list of not-upgraded packages. It will appear every time you run apt.

**Optional**: If you wish to fix the problem instead of living with it, the repair would depend upon what blocked the release-upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04. You can usually discover the blocker by running `sudo apt dist-upgrade` and then carefully reading all the output for clues.